# Why does it not show when you get downvoted?

Tags: discussion, support, voting

Normally, when you gain reputation, it shows a little number at the top right of the cup with a star on it (next to inbox).

Why isn't it showing when you lose reputation as when you get downvoted? I sometimes come and get very surprised when I come to one of my questions or answers and see I lost some reputation without being warned...

Comment: Before it used to do that. Something like -x reps was display in red.

Comment: @Henry Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @grg It's what I saw when I first joined Stack Exchange. It was in the old top bar. I will go over some screenshots to see.

Comment: Doesn't clicking on the notification number show how that number was created including listing the downvotes (As I don't get bonuses from editing anymore then if it is not a multiple of 5 then there has been downvotes - @Thinkr is more difficult to see as they can get 2 for an edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oded, an employee at the time of writing, said

> Negative reputation changes are... well... negative. So we are not in a hurry to let you know about them

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/219665/222623

You can see down votes more quickly than in the summary which should update once a day at a minimum by inspecting your reputation page or the posts by vote if you have few posts.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation&sort=post